# OpenVPN connecting, but not changing public IP

Tags: command-line, openvpn, ip

When i log into the VPN, i get a pop up saying that the connection is successful. The nm-applet icon in my (i3) status bar appears with a lock, as if i am connected to a VPN. My VPN connection gets a nice little tick next to it to tell me i'm connected.

However my public ip address does not change.

My status bar reads VPN: no

Most importantly, when i try to connect to csf via ssh:

> ssh username@csf.university.itservices.ac.uk
>
> ssh: Could not resolve hostname csf.university.itservices.ac.uk: Name or service not known

I have re-configured the package repositories; uninstalled and re-installed the packages many times.

It had worked fine before yesterday afternoon. The status bar would read VPN: yes. Now the status bar seems to think that my computer has an Ethernet connection. Instead of a VPN connection.

Comment: Some clarifications might help, such as what VPN you are using, what package or software you installed, what "status bar" you talk about. When you connect your VPN, does a tun0 or tun1 interface appear in the output of ifconfig?

Comment: How do you see that your IP is not changing? Are you connecting to VPN via CLI or NetworkManager GUI? Edit your question with the output of `resolvectl` with VPN up. Show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`. Report back to @heynnema